# D3 data not updating through onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've built out a color coded map using D3 and want to take the next step of allowing a user to look at the data by year by clicking year buttons. I've attached an onclick function to each button and this function updates my displayYear variable. I threw in a console.log to make sure this variable is being updated correctly, and it is. However, for some reason my map never updates, it remains at its initial value no matter what is clicked. My HTML and Javascript/D3 code is below:

relevant HTML:

```
<button onclick="setYear(0)">2009</button>
<button onclick="setYear(1)">2010</button>
<button onclick="setYear(2)">2011</button>
<button onclick="setYear(3)">2012</button>
<button onclick="setYear(4)">2013</button>
<button onclick="setYear(5)">2014</button>
```

relevant JS:

```
//Bind premium and map data and create one path per mapData feature

var displayYear = 0;
function setYear(index) {
    displayYear = index;
    console.log(displayYear);
}           

premSvg.selectAll("path")
       .data(mapData.features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .style("fill", function(d) {
             //Get data value
             var value = d.properties.premium[displayYear].value;

             if (value) {
                   //If value exists…
                   return premColor(value);
             } else {
                   //If value is undefined…
                   return "#ccc";
             }
        })
        .style("stroke","grey")
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
              return d.properties.name + ": $" + d3.format(",")(Math.round(d.properties.premium[displayYear].value));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up wrapping code to update my "path" fill in my setYear function:

```
function setYear(index) {
    displayYear = index;

    premSvg.selectAll("path")
           .style("fill", function(d) {
                //Get data value
                var value = d.properties.premium[displayYear].value;

                if (value) {
                    //If value exists…
                    return premColor(value);
                } else {
                    //If value is undefined…
                    return "#ccc";
                }
            })
            .style("stroke","grey")
            .append("title")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.properties.name + ": $" + d3.format(",")(Math.round(d.properties.premium[displayYear].value));
            });
}

function setYear(index) {
                displayYear = index;

                premSvg.selectAll("path")
                        .style("fill", function(d) {
                            //Get data value
                        var value = d.properties.premium[displayYear].value;

                        if (value) {
                            //If value exists…
                            return premColor(value);
                        } else {
                            //If value is undefined…
                            return "#ccc";
                        }
                    })
                    .style("stroke","grey");

                premSvg.selectAll("title")
                       .text(function(d) {
                        return d.properties.name + ": $" + d3.format(",")(Math.round(d.properties.premium[displayYear].value));
                });
            }
```